# How do I get a loader/spinner while exporting data of the SlickGrid?

Tags: angular, typescript, slickgrid

Im using slickgrid (2.12.2) and angular 8. I wanna know how can i show a loader/spinner while the data is been exported to csv, excel or file. Because if the data is large, the exportation take some time, and the person who is using might think that nothing is happening...

Comment: You need one boolean variable. which tracks your loader or spinner. when your perticular event starts variable becomes True and after event finished again variable becomes false. and in Angular template you need to pass value of variable to loader or spinner.

Comment: but im using the slickgrid export options ...that are avaliable on the grid menu. I dont know how to capture this events

Comment: @Geovane Scheer Just to be sure, are you using the angular-slickgrid package, or the javascript library?

Comment: @Wingnod this https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid

Comment: I'm guessing your using the 'exportToFile' function, which returns a promise? If you are, then you can set the flag (that binds to the spinner) to true before invoking 'exportToFile', and do .then((value) {
    flag = false;
});

Comment: im not using the 'exportToFile' function. I just have set the properties 'enableExcelExport', 'enableExport' to true in the gridOptions...

Comment: but i will try to use as you said

Comment: @Geovane Scheer Apologies, I jumped to conclusions. I'll take a look at what you just mentioned.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted but that was a valid question, so I upvoted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that I'm the author of Angular-Slickgrid. From the question and answer that I saw, it seems that I was missing this feature explained in my Wikis (there are a lot of Wikis, please read them) and so I updated both Wikis [Export to Excel](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/wiki/Export-to-Excel#show-loading-process-spinner) and [Export to File (CSV/TabDelimited)](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/wiki/Export-to-File#show-loading-process-spinner), the [Grouping Example](https://ghiscoding.github.io/Angular-Slickgrid/#/grouping) is the only demo showing this feature because that is the only one that can have lots of data (if you choose to use 50k rows from the demo and use grouping).

Here's the updated Wiki for the Excel Export

**Option 1 (recommended)**

View

```html
<span [hidden]="!processing">
   <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-lg fa-fw"></i>
</span>

<angular-slickgrid gridId="grid2"
                     [dataset]="dataset"
                     [columnDefinitions]="columnDefinitions"
                     [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
                     (onGridBeforeExportToExcel)="processing = true"
                     (onGridAfterExportToExcel)="processing = false"
                     (onAngularGridCreated)="angularGridReady($event)">
</angular-slickgrid>
```

Component

```
export class MyComponent() implements OnInit {
  processing = false;
}
```

As per @Wingnod's answer you can also subscribe to the event in your code, but it's better to simply use the Event Emitters `(onGridBeforeExportToExcel)` since you won't need to care about the unsubscribe and the code is cleaner. If for some reason you do wish to subscribe to the event, you can do it this way

**Option 2 (not recommended)**

View

```html
<angular-slickgrid gridId="grid2"
        [dataset]="dataset"
        [columnDefinitions]="columnDefinitions"
        [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
        (onAngularGridCreated)="angularGridReady($event)">
</angular-slickgrid>
```

Component

```
export class GridGroupingComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  exportBeforeSub: Subscription;
  exportAfterSub: Subscription;

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.exportBeforeSub.unsubscribe();
    this.exportAfterSub.unsubscribe();
  }

  angularGridReady(angularGrid: AngularGridInstance) {
    this.angularGrid = angularGrid;

    // display a spinner while downloading
    this.exportBeforeSub = this.angularGrid.exportService.onGridBeforeExportToFile.subscribe(() => this.processing = true);
    this.exportAfterSub = this.angularGrid.exportService.onGridAfterExportToFile.subscribe(() => this.processing = false);
  }
}
```

You can see that Option 1 is a lot cleaner and easier to implement.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this should work for you. According to the Angular-SlickGrid source, the `exportService.exportToFile` function returns a promise.

You can set a flag before invoking the function, and use the 'then' block of the returned promise to stop the spinner after the export completes.

```
@Component({
    ...
})
export class MyComponent {
    loading: boolean = false;

    constructor (private exportService: ExportService ) {
        ...
    }

    exportToCSV (): Promise<bool> {
        return this.exportService.exportToFile({
            ...
        });
    }

    onExportBtnClicked () {
        this.loading = true;

        this.exportToCSV.then(() => {
            // Assuming it succeeds.
            this.loading = false;
        });
    }
}
```

Angular-SlickGrid also has the following output properties.

```
  @Output() onGridBeforeExportToFile = this.exportService.onGridBeforeExportToFile;
  @Output() onGridAfterExportToFile = this.exportService.onGridAfterExportToFile;
  @Output() onGridBeforeExportToExcel = this.excelExportService.onGridBeforeExportToExcel;
  @Output() onGridAfterExportToExcel = this.excelExportService.onGridAfterExportToExcel;
```

Internally, the menu extension for Angular-SlickGrid uses `ExportService.exportToFile`, which emits an event, which (as shown above) is outputted from the angular-slickgrid component.

```
@Injectable()
export class ExportService {
    ...
    onGridBeforeExportToFile = new Subject<boolean>();
    onGridAfterExportToFile = new Subject<{ content?: string; filename: string; format: string; useUtf8WithBom: boolean; }>();
}
```

They are public so you can access them on the ExportService directly. You can set your spinner flag to true when `onGridBeforeExportToFile` emits an event, and false when `onGridAfterExportToFile` emits.

To summarise, the export service is the source of all things related to exporting for the Angular-SlickGrid library, whether you click a custom-made button to export, or click 'Export in CSV format' from the menu extension, etc.

Comment: it worked!! i used the properties you mention, "onGridBeforeExportToExcel", "onGridAfterExportToExcel"... and inside them the spinner control (hide/show). Thanks !

Comment: Like this on the HTML

<angular-slickgrid *ngIf="showGrid" gridId="grid1" [columnDefinitions]="columnDefinitions"
  [gridOptions]="gridOptions" [dataset]="dataset" (onGridBeforeExportToExcel)="beforeExcel()" (onGridAfterExportToExcel)="afterExcel()">
</angular-slickgrid>

Comment: That's great! I was worried for a second, because I couldn't get it working in Stackblitz, but it's good that things worked out for you.

Comment: That is the correct answer, using the `(onGridBeforeExportToFile)` and (after) are the prefered way since you don't need to unsubscribe. The [Grouping Example](https://ghiscoding.github.io/Angular-Slickgrid/#/grouping) is the only example which I demo this exact feature, on this [line](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/blob/master/src/app/examples/grid-grouping.component.html#L52) because that is the only one with lots of data (when it's grouped and you use 50k data). You should up vote this answer... and up vote my library of course ;)   I'm the author BTW.

Comment: Also there are a lot of Wikis that I created, if you find that some could be updated, then let me know, you can open an issue with the changes. I think I forgot to add code sample for this spinner feature actually. Thanks